# WCF Service vs Windows Service

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-services, compact-framework, wcf

I’m writing a service that will be used only within an internal network.  I will be accessing this from a mobile client using the compact framework (3.5).  I’m new to WCF – will this provide me with anything that I won’t get from creating a standard windows service?  Are there any disadvantages to using WCF in this environment?

Comment: A standard Windows Service is a process that runs on that particular machine and does something on that machine. It doesn't have any "outgoing" communications by default - that's what WCF brings to the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a WCF service hosted in a Windows Service?

These are different things. A Windows Service is a process and a WCF Service is a handler/implementor of protocol and functionality.

**EDIT** Sorry if I sounded too blunt. You might host a WCF service in a Windows host but you could also host it in IIS/WAS or any other .NET application. With IIS/WAS you get a lot of extras such as authentication, process recycling etc.

With WCF you can implement very interopable REST/JSON services but you can also pick very advanced stuff like WS-* features.

Look them up.

Comment: +1 wanted to know what the difference was between the two, this told me what i needed to know.

Comment: Additional information from MSDN on how to host a WCF Service inside a Windows Service: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.100).aspx
and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734781.aspx